# Generating deterministic number from data

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, cryptography, key

I am trying to deterministically generate an output integer from some input string, such that all inputs of the same string will give me the same output integer within a range (0 ... X) as an index into an array of length X. Each element in the array is a pair (GUID, aes-256 key). I need this for deterministically selecting an encryption key based on the data-to-be-encrypted (this data is used as a DB index - hence the need for determinism).

Currently, I am converting the string to a char array, summing all the character values and then using the modulus operator to map into my index range. Expressed in C# as:

```
var index = data.ToCharArray().Sum(x => x) % keys.Count;
```

However, this only works as long as the set of keys never change - because of the `% keys.Count` statement. Which means my application can never introduce new encryption keys into the key ring without breaking all the lookups fields and the indexes based on their values.

Is there some clever way of doing the above, but adding the requirement that I can introduce (not remove) new keys and not change the outcome. Such that:

```
Input: "FooFoo" Output: 2 for 3 keys
Input: "FooFoo" Output: 2 for 5 keys
Input: "FooFoo" Output: 2 for 8 keys
...
```

I think I can solve this by adding an hashmap which stores hashes of the strings and the keylength they were first encrypted with, and then uses that keylength for all eternity. However, that's quite a roundabout way of achieving it if there is some algorithmic- or mathematical way of achieving the same.

Alternatively, when the application launches to production we just need to add enough encryption keys that we never need to add more through the lifetime of the application (hopefully at least a decade).

Comment: To generate a deterministic number from data the obvious idea is to use a hash function.  How many bits is the number you want?

Comment: Well, I want the index into an array, which I would like to be able to add to during lifetime of the application. But certainly 6-8bit would be more than enough.

Comment: Does the indexing need to be cryptographically secure?  Crypto hashes are usually large.  If you want smaller outputs then fold a large crypto hash to reduce it: 256 -> 128 -> 64 -> 32 bit or else use a simpler non-crypto hash with a larger set of possible output sizes, such as the [FNV hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function).

Comment: No. The indexing does not need to be secure.
This is a solution, however it only works if I keep my set of keys static and have an amount of keys equal to the max value of the bits from the hashing function. If I select a 6-bit hashing function, I need 64 keys at application start and forever thereafter, instead of e.g. starting with 10 and then adding as we go.

This can work and might be the only viable solution, but it doesn't bring me much compared to my current solution other than determining a fixed number of keys for me (256, 128, 64 etc)

Comment: Don't use an array, use a Dictionary. Then use the full SHA-256 hash output as the Dictionary key to lookup your (GUID, aes-key) pair.

Comment: That's similar to the solution I proposed myself in the original question. It can work, but requires I maintain this enormous dictionary with entries for all Strings I ever encrypt. It can work, but it's unwieldy.